# group by in Flask-MongoAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask, mongodb-query, mongoalchemy

i stared new project with flask web-framework with mongoDB. i also used database and access data using **Flask-MongoAlchemy**. i tried work on different query like .all(), .filter_by(), .get() its work nice. but problem is that how to use aggregate funcation in Flask-MongoAlchemy ? for example i want to use group_by.

i tried following but its still not working.

```
db.User.qroup_by(name)
```

its gives following error

```
'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'group_by'
```

Comment: Please try to add more code, give more information on what `db` is.

Comment: db is instance of db = MongoAlchemy(app)

Comment: same problem with order_by